# Tool to find and replace numbers based on range in Unicode text file

Tags: regex, text, unicode

I've been seaching all over and am out of ideas, so I'll try my luck here.
What I need to do is simple... or so I thought.

I need to process a lot of Unicode files that all follow the same structure in a Windows environment. In these files are lines that contain "valuexxx" where xxx is a three digit number. I need to be able to replace valuexxx with a string, depending on what value xxx is. A crude way of explaining what I need to do is

- if `xxx >= 270` and `xxx < 310` then replace `valuexxx` with some text.
- if `xxx >= 311` and `xxx < 350` then replace `valuexxx` with some other text.

The ranges may need to be fine tuned later.

First I thought I'd use Notepad++ or FNR.exe as they use regular expressions, but as I have found out regular expressions can not do numeric value comparing. I did find that I could possibly solve it by testing for valid character combinations, but this will not work as the range may need to change and re-editing all character combinations will be too much of a hassle for the people who I need to solve this for.

So I moved on to Gawk, it seems to be able to do the comparisons I need, but it appears it can't process Unicode text files. I'd prefer not to have to convert from Unicode to something else as these files can contain multiple languages like Chinese, Japanese, Thai etc etc.

I can't program these kind of things myself so I need some sort of tool that can do the above. Any suggestions?

Comment: I see I'm quickly getting negative votes. I don't mind that, but if the answer is so easy, why not post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a ready-made tool exists for that, but you can do something like this very simply, for example in a Python script.

I'm assuming that by Unicode you mean `UTF-8`-encoded files. Then (in Python 3), you'd just have to do this to define your replacement texts:

```
import re
repl = {(270,310): "some text",
        (311,350): "some other text",
        # etc., add more here
       }
regex = re.compile(r"value(\d{3})")

def replace(match):
    value = int(match.group(1))
    for item in repl:
        if item[0] <= value < item[1]:
            return repl[item]
```

Then you could read the files, for example all files ending in `.txt`:

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    with open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        content = f.read()
```

and then write the corrected file:

```
    with open(filename + ".new", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(regex.sub(replace, content))
```

That's it. There's no error checking done (for example if the three-digit number is not found in `repl`), but I think this should get you started.

Comment: Thank's Tim. Python seems to be the tool I am looking for. Thanks for the samples, I'll be experimenting with them, very helpful.